# Unable to retrieve element through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

html file:

```
  <div id ="main">
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
//create a div
var divElem = $('<div class="divText"></div>');

//create input element inside it
var inhtml = "<input type='text' id='12345' />";

//add to page
$(divElem).html(inhtml).appendTo('#main')
```

**Following does not work as it is unable to find input element:**

```
//retrieve input element
$('#12345').val('hello')
```

Following works:

```
document.getElementById('12345').value = 'hello'
```

Following works:

```
var ipElem = $(inhtml);
$(divElem).append(ipElem).appendTo('#main')
$(ipElem).val('hello')
```

Can anyone tell why first version of retrieving element does not work in jquery? (just starting with jquery... :) )

Edit:
I think '12345' works but not some weird id like: mytext0.15942923246580176
See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9PVNb/4/

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9PVNb/

Comment: i try your code (just add a ";" after var inhtml = "<input type='text' id='12345' />";) and it works....

Comment: *"//retrieve input element: $('#12345').val('hello')"* - it's not retrieving. it's setting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're wrapping `divElem` in jQuery object twice:

```
var divElem = $('<div class="divText"></div>');
var inhtml = "<input type='text' id='12345' />";

$(divElem).html(inhtml).appendTo('#main') // Nop '$(divElem)' plus missing `;`
divElem.append(inhtml).appendTo('#main'); // Yup
```

**EDIT:**

> *Edit: I think '12345' works but not some weird id like: mytext0.15942923246580176*

Your code at http://jsfiddle.net/9PVNb/4/ isn't working because:

```
// Your `id` has a `.` which you didn't escape
var elemid = 'mytext0.15942923246580176';
```

You can make it work by doing this:

```
alert($('#' + elemid).val()); //undefined. DOES NOT WORK
alert($('#' + elemid.replace('.', '\\.')).val()); // hello world IT WORKS!
```

Comment: Though not the best practise, it's irrelevant if you wrap a jquery object in another jquery object. jquery will take care of that. (Even: `$($($($($(divElem))))).html(inhtml).appendTo('#main');​` would work)

Comment: @Yoshi I have updated this. http://jsfiddle.net/9PVNb/4/  Some issue with id value I suppose

Comment: Yes, escaping dots was required in jquery but not with traditional javascript getElementById. Thanks!! I was so confused.

Answer (score 1):

works here: http://jsfiddle.net/xvKcd/

basic check:

- are you using $(document).ready()? your code may be firing up before the element you needed was loaded.
- did you load jQuery before anything else?
- typos?

Comment: Thanks. I was using a '.' in id and I needed to escape that dot.